Buttons do not trigger the creation of an object in AR Unity
I have this task. I need to implement two buttons, when you press them, the prefab will appear. at startup I can see that the placeable prefab field is updated, but the actual pressing of the button does not happen (I added log output to the console when the button is pressed). I don't understand what the problem is, because I created the project through AR Core and through 3D. Nothing works. Help, please




using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;


[RequireComponent(typeof(ARRaycastManager))]
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ARRaycastManager raycastManager;
    private GameObject spawnedObject;
    private List<GameObject> placedPrefabsList = new List<GameObject>();
    [SerializeField]
    private int maxPrefabSpawnCount;
    private int placedPrefabCount;
    public GameObject placeablePrefab;
    static List<ARRaycastHit> s_Hits = new List<ARRaycastHit>();
    private void Awake()
    {
        raycastManager = GetComponent<ARRaycastManager>();
    }

    bool TryGetTouchPosition(out Vector2 touchPosition)
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0) // Проверяем, есть ли хотя бы одно касание
        {
            Debug.Log("Input.touchCount: " + Input.touchCount);  // Выводим количество касаний

            if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                Debug.Log("Touch detected at position: " + Input.GetTouch(0).position);
                touchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Touch phase is not Began: " + Input.GetTouch(0).phase);
            }
        }

        touchPosition = default;
        return false;
    }



    private void Update()
    {
        if (!TryGetTouchPosition(out Vector2 touchPosition))
        {
            return;
        }
        if (raycastManager.Raycast(touchPosition, s_Hits, TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon))
        {
            var hitPose = s_Hits[0].pose;
            if (placedPrefabCount < maxPrefabSpawnCount)
            {
                Debug.Log("1");

                SpawnPrefab(hitPose);
            }
        }
    }
    private void SpawnPrefab(Pose hitPose)
    {
        spawnedObject = Instantiate(placeablePrefab, hitPose.position, hitPose.rotation);
        placedPrefabsList.Add(spawnedObject);
        placedPrefabCount++;
    }

    public void SetPrefabType(GameObject prefabType)
    {
        placeablePrefab = prefabType;
    }
}

I'm trying to make certain prefabs appear when I click on them

You dont show having an event system, do you have one?

@BugFinder after fixing the image embedding -> the second one shows there is at least a GameObject EventSystem in the scene ;)

Does the button react to interactions at all - meaning does it change color etc when hovering/pressing the button? Also check that the EventSystem has the correct input module (legacy input system vs new InputActions)

@derHugo yap. when i click the button it turns gray

So, pressing the button sets the prefab to be created, but then do you also tap on the PlaneWithinPolygon to instantiate? Pressing the button does not create, the Update does that (in an unusual fashion). On a secondary note, you don't need placedPrefabCount as you can use placedPrefabsList.Count.
